# Dropdownmenu in Streamlit without brackets and quotes

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, streamlit

I am using streamlit for displaying a dropdown menu based on a csv list (symbols.csv).

This is how the csv list looks:

[image]

This is the code I am writing:

```
def choosing_asset():

with open('symbols.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)


option = st.sidebar.selectbox('Select your asset',data)

name = option[0]
ticker = option[1]

return(name,ticker)
```

And this is how streamlit is displaying the dropdownmenu:

[image]

I would like to remove those brackets and quotes from the dropdownmenu, I would like to show only in the format "Bitcoin, BTC-USD" like in the csv file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: in data you have lists which you should convert to string - or simply read csv as normal text file `open()`, `read()`, `close()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nested list like this

```
data = [ ['Bitcoin', 'BTC-USD'], ['Ethereum', 'ETH-USD'] ]
```

and you have to convert sublists to strings using ie. `join`

```
data = [','.join(row) for row in data]
```

Or you should read it as normal text file

```
with open('symbols.csv', newline='') as f:
    data = list(f)
    data = [line.strip() for line in data]
```

or

```
with open('symbols.csv', newline='') as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines()
```

---

**BTW:**

And if you want to skip first row with `Company_name,Company_ticker`

```
data = data[1:]
```